# now function for displaying Date and Time not working through ActivePerl

Tags: perl

I want to display the present date and time in perl using now() function. I am running this script using Active Perl software but I am getting error.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Date::Parse;
$date = str2time(now());
print "$date\n";
```

I am getting error as:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>perl test.pl
Can't locate Date/Parse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib
.) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.
```

Please help.

Comment: If you want the current Unix time, why don't you just use [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html "perldoc -f time")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have module `Date::Parse` installed by default in ActivePerl.

You can fix this with:

```
ppm install Date::Parse
```

This works for me for ActivePerl 5.16 default install.

Comment: After installing module, I get C:\Users\admin\Desktop>perl test.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::now called at test.pl line 3.

Comment: Try using `localtime()` or `gmtime()` instead of `now()`